# confusing behaviour of fork() system call in c

Tags: c, fork

I was checking behaviour of fork system call. I executed the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int count=0;
int main()
{
int i;
int n=3;
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
{
printf(" %d ",i);
fork();
} 
}
```

I had a thought that having `fork()` inside a `for loop` is similar to writing it in series i.e.

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
   fork();
```

is similar to

```
fork();
fork();
fork();
```

I tried to draw a recursion tree for the same
[image]

I expected the output to be eight consecutive 3's. But output was following:

```
 1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
```

Note:compiled and executed in gcc

Comment: I think you may find your output a bit different if you flush the stdout line buffer with each call. It should contain, one 1, two 2's, and four 3's.

Comment: output buffering is involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your expectations are wrong, you will get more than just 3's output. Second, your `stdout` line buffer is retained when you fork, and thus will copy previously `printf`-ed content to the forked processes as part of the process duplicate. A modified version of your program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=3;++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        fork();
    }
}
```

will produce output *similar* to the following:

```
1 2 3 2 3 3 3
```

The added flush empties the current-process' stdout line prior to the fork, thereby eliminating replicated output. The order may be slightly different, but will always start with `1`, end with `3`, Further, any `1` will always be followed by at least one `2`, and any `2` always followed by at least one `3`

Answer (score 1):

It will print like that
1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
because 1 time for parent and 1 time for child.
Fork() :- for parent and child.

So loop is rotating 4 times thats

1 2 3   for parent 1 2 3 for child

2(Parent and child)  * 4(Loop rotate) =  it will print 8 times (1 2 3)

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been asked before. You can find the similar question here.

[Visually what happens to fork() in a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793402/visually-what-happens-to-fork-in-a-for-loop)

I hope that helps^^

Answer (score 1):

because `stdout` output is buffered by default, forking the process will cause to  duplicate the buffer and when each process is finished each buffer will be flushed.

using :

```
fprintf(stderr," %d ",i);
```

will make the program output :

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

because you are making the printf statement in the loop ( from 1 to 3 )

the following statement would help you trace the output :

```
fprintf(stderr," %d:%d ",i,getpid());
```

which will output (example) :

```
1:24100  2:24100  2:24101  3:24100  3:24102  3:24101  3:24103
```