# How many processes were created

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

How many processes are created?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think there are 32 processes created but I want to double check that my logic is sound. The first process creates 4 processes each, with an i value of 0. Those four processes then create 3 more processes each, with a value an i value of 1. Those 3 processes then each create 2 more processes each, with an i value of 2. Those 2 processes then each create 1 more process with an i value of 3.

(4+3+3+3+3+2+2+2+1+1)+1 = 32

The plus one is for the first process.

Does this sound correct? Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose you shoved a `printf("Hello\n")` somewhere in there and just started counting ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I did but if I put the printf before the fork I got 15, after, 31. I don't why it would matter.

Comment: Putting it after ensures the started process prints *before* that processes increment on the control loop and the subsequent conditional test. Putting it before will skip that step once for each new iteration on each new process.

Comment: Why do you think i has a value of zero for all of the 4 children created by the eldest process?  Seems to me that the value of i will be different in each child.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for **N** fork statements, the number of processes formed are **2^N**.For more details on how it works, it has already been answered in the link given below:
[Visually what happens to fork() in a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793402/visually-what-happens-to-fork-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

`2^N-1` as for first iteration only one child will be created and from 2 iteration onwards the fork will create `2^N` Childs.

Somethings like it will be created:

> ```
>                   1 
>             2             2
>          3    3        3    3
>        4 4  4  4     4  4  4  4
> ```